# Sorting facets in ggplot using facet_grid

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, facet-grid

I have scoured SO trying to find a fix for this. I've found a few answers, but when I apply them, they don't work as I am intending (or maybe I"m just doing something wrong). Basically, I have a dataset that I am trying to plot using facet_grid. My problem is twofold:

1. I want the the grids to be sorted according to a numeric value
2. I have a grouping variable that I also want sorted by a numeric value (descending) but I want to be able to assign an ascending count number to a group (i.e., highest group gets a 1, 2nd highest gets a 2, etc) so that I can select the highest group first, then the 2nd highest group, etc. I have many many groups and the values and names that come with those groups are random, so I don't want to manually assign the values.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
df <- data.frame(grp.name = c("T","F","P","T","F","P","T","F","P","T","F","P"),
                 grp.num   = c(0.9954,0.8754,0.5006,0.9954,0.8754,0.5006,0.9954,0.8754,0.5006,0.9954,0.8754,0.5006),   
                 ind.name  = c("L","N","M","C","A","B","I","H","G","D","F","E"),   
                 amount = c(48.41234, 48.12343, 46.83546, 25.9454, 26.01568, 24.946454, 21.1, 21.4545, 20.1, 20.8, 21.5644, 16.5) )


df <- df[order(-df$grp.num,-df$amount),]

t <-  ggplot(data=subset(df,grp.name=="T"), aes(grp.name, amount, fill=grp.name, group=grp.name, shape=grp.name, facets=grp.name)) +
  geom_col(width=0.5, position = position_dodge(width=0.6)) + 
  facet_grid(grp.name + paste0("Number: ",grp.num)  ~ ind.name + paste0("Number: ",amount),switch = "y") 
t
```

My reason for subsetting just group T in this case is because I want to plot out the 10 highest groups and then stack them in another plot using grid.arrange. I would like to be able to just subset group 1, then 2, then 3, etc without knowing the name, because, again, these names change.

Here is what I get. Instead of sorting the facets by `amount` it is sorting them alphabetically by `ind.name`. I would like the "L" group first, as it has the highest amount, followed by "C", then "I", then "D". Again, I don't want to do this manually, as these values change and I am redoing these plots over many many groups.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, its simpler to carry out the preparation of data prior to passing to the ggplot function.

Faceting order works on factors, so convert `ind.name` to a factor ordered by `amount`. Create a `grp_nr` based on factor order.

Revised following OP's comments and new dataset.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(ind.name = fct_rev(fct_reorder(ind.name, amount)),
         amount = round(amount, 3),
         grp.num_lev = as.integer(fct_rev(factor(grp.num))),
         grp.num = round(grp.num, 3))%>%
  filter(grp.num_lev==1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(grp.name, amount, fill=grp.name, group=grp.name, shape=grp.name)) +   
  geom_col(width=0.5, position = position_dodge(width=0.6)) +   
  facet_grid(grp.name + paste0("Number: ", grp.num)  ~ ind.name + paste0("Number: ", amount), switch = "y")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(grp.name   = c("T","F","P","T","F","P","T","F","P","T","F","P"),
                 grp.num   = c(0.9954,0.8754,0.5006,0.9954,0.8754,0.5006,0.9954,0.8754,0.5006,0.9954,0.8754,0.5006),   
                 ind.name  = c("L","N","M","C","A","B","I","H","G","D","F","E"),   
                 amount = c(48.41234, 48.12343, 46.83546, 25.9454, 26.01568, 24.946454, 21.1, 21.4545, 20.1, 20.8, 21.5644, 16.5) )
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, but only solved my first problem. How can I create a variable that assigns a "1" to the group with the highest grp.num, a "2" to the group with the 2nd highest grp.num, etc?

Comment: So, right now I have groups T, F and P. T has the highest value for ```grp.num```, so I want a new variable that will assign a 1 to this. That way instead of subsetting using ```filter(grp.name=="T")```  I would subset using something like ```filter(grp=="1")```. The reason for this is because the group values change for each iteration. I don't want to have to look up which group is highest each time. I want to just select the highest group and the 2nd highest group and the 3rd highest group, etc. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you! This isn't exactly what I was looking for but this code definitely helps. So, I think this is what I want:  ```df %>% 
  mutate(ind.name = fct_rev(fct_reorder(ind.name, amount)),
         grp.num = fct_rev(factor(grp.num)),
         grp.num_lev = as.integer(factor(grp.num)))%>% 
  filter(grp.num_lev==1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(grp.name, amount, fill=grp.name, group=grp.name, shape=grp.name)) +
  geom_col(width=0.5, position = position_dodge(width=0.6)) +
  facet_grid(grp.name + paste0("Number: ", grp.num)  ~ ind.name + paste0("Number: ", amount), switch = "y")```

Comment: That's even simpler, I suppose it saves you from working out which of T, P or what ever grp.name is the highest value. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Actually, shoot. This doesn't work. In my actual dataset, the values for ```amount``` are many decimal places long and I need to round them to 3 decimal places. I had ```facet_grid(grp.name + paste0("Number: ", round(grp.num,3)) ~ ind.name + paste0("Number: ", round(amount,3))``` but, because we have turned these variables into factors, ```round()``` won't work.

Comment: `amount` is not a factor, it is used as an ordering value for converting ind.name into a factor; So it should not make any difference, indeed amount in the example is to 1 dp. and this does not fail. the answer should work, you just need to adjust the rounding  as set out in the comment; the rounding could be done in a call to mutate, prior to the call to `ggplot`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant for ```grp.num```

Comment: I'm sorry. that is still not working correctly. I really appreciated all you're time and help on this. If we update the original df to have multiple dp for both ```grp.num``` & ```amount``` then amount doesn't round. ```df <- data.frame(
  grp.name   = c("T","F","P","T","F","P","T","F","P","T","F","P"), 
  grp.num   = c(0.9954,0.8754,0.5006,0.9954,0.8754,0.5006,0.9954,0.8754,0.5006,0.9954,0.8754,0.5006),
  ind.name  = c("L","N","M","C","A","B","I","H","G","D","F","E"),
  amount = c(48.41234, 48.12343, 46.83546, 25.9454, 26.01568, 24.946454, 21.1, 21.4545, 20.1, 20.8, 21.5644, 16.5)
) ```

Comment: Please add the new data frame into the question so that all relevant information is in one place.

Comment: Check out revised edit to answer?

Comment: Edited. And thank you so much! This worked!

Comment: Great: if the answer resolves your problem please consider accepting and upvoting [Accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
t <-  ggplot(data=subset(df,grp.name=="T"), aes(grp.name, amount, fill=grp.name, group=grp.name, shape=grp.name)) +
  geom_col(width=0.5, position = position_dodge(width=0.6)) + 
  facet_grid(grp.name + paste0("Number: ",grp.num)  ~ reorder(ind.name, -amount, mean) + paste0("Number: ",amount),switch = "y") 
t
```

[image]

Comment: That worked!! But only solved my first problem. How can I create a variable that assigns a "1" to the group with the highest ```grp.num```, a "2" to the group with the 2nd highest ```grp.num```, etc?